# Changing a readonly string field

Tags: c#, string, fixed, readonly, unsafe

Why can I do this? Is it a bug?

```
Debug.WriteLine (System.Boolean.FalseString); // output: "False"

fixed (char* xx = System.Boolean.FalseString) {
    xx[1] = 'X';
}

Debug.WriteLine (System.Boolean.FalseString); // output: "FXlse"
```

Then, the `FalseString` have the new value.

I dont know if is a bug, because `FalseString` is a readonly field.

Is there a security problem?

Is the managed model not really secure?

Can I make changes from satellite libraries, that can crash the main process?

Comment: There is a reason the keyword is called "unsafe"

Comment: What about this is confusing you? You're reaching into memory and modifying it in a way that doesn't care about readonly-ness.

Comment: I'm not confused.

I understand that I am accessing memory with pointers.

In my opinion, it seems to me a design error and concept of the framework.

I just thought that readonly were created in a protected or read-only (controlled) part of memory.

Actually the word "unsafe" is placed in the code that does the unsafe, which is confusing.

Readonly should be readonly and unsafe should release my own data and not allow me to modify code data that were NOT marked as "unsafe"

Comment: how do you think memory works? How would you NOT be able to point to something and change it? Do you think it's a locker-like system, where you can close it and only if you have the key can open it?

Comment: more or less ... there are readonly memory page controled by processor ...

Answer (score 0):

As Brandon Ibbotson and Dispersia have already mentioned, this is not considered a security vulnerability because of the
["It rather involved being on the other side of this airtight hatchway: ..."](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070807-00/?p=25683) principle, as humorously articulated by Raymond Chen on many of his [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) posts about similar concerns raised by others.